# Is "The India way" , "The Toyota way" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Is the book title "The India Way" grammatically correct ? Or should it be "The Indian way" or "The India's way".

Because we write, "The American way"

But I have also found one similar example, "The Toyota way".

What do you guys think?  Since this book is published massively, so, the title must be correct, then what meaning grammatically does this title convey?

Comment: *Since this book is published massively, so, the title must be correct* This form of argument is invalid.

Comment: Thanks Vane for responding, but isn't "the Indian way" is the way of doing things in India? How is this different from "The India way"?

Comment: "Indian" in the US has a different meaning, or multiple meanings, as it was formerly used for Native Americans and is still sometimes used (including by Native American organisations) so there may be a desire to avoid that ambiguity, depending on what the target audience is. But certainly noun+way is grammatical.

Comment: "The American way" is synonymous with "The American way of life" or the "way of life of the Americans." If you title a book "The Indian Way" this will imply you are talking about the way of life of the Indians. What is the book actually about?

Comment: @WeatherVane I can't find any strong evidence of *country name* + *way* being idiomatic. In fact, if someone said "the Germany way" I'd assume they were a non-native speaker. Ngrams show that there is no evidence of "the Germany way" while "the German way" has plenty of attestation.

Comment: @GArthurBrown OP did not ask if it is idiomatic, but grammatical. It's a book title anyway. As for "The Toyota way" I don't think there is an adjective.

Comment: @WeatherVane Since it is a book title, I think it is important that we convey weather or not it is common usage. The answer is: "the India way" would not be used by native speakers of most types of English. "The Indian Way" reads naturally and does not cause people to question why they worded it that way.

Comment: @GArthurBrown since it is a book title, they can name it however they please. It was commented that "The Indian Way" could be taken as a 'loaded' title, or misconstrued.

Comment: @WeatherVane Surely there will be additional information on the cover, including a picture, that resolve any ambiguity about which meaning of "Indian" the book addresses.

Comment: Thanks @GArthurBrown and Weather Vane for your insightful discussion, GArthurBrown, the book is on Indian foreign policy and strategies. The author is a diplomat turned politician, S. Jaishankar, the incumbent Indian External Affairs Minister.

Comment: It appears this book is already available and titled "The India Way." There's at least one other book with that title, and a number with "The Indian Way" as well. I think there are probably a few considerations as to why India is used differently from Indian, including the numerous different ethnic identities in the nation. For government policy, it makes sense to use India for this book.